# Trying to generate a random integer within a specific range then have it displayed inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, here's what I have (I am running JQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/111/

```html
The computer chose <span id="x"></span>.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = function getRandomInt(1, 4) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1
    };
    $('#x').html(x);
}
```

I feel like the issue has to do with this `$('#x').html(x);`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because your `x` function has two integers set as the arguments, which is syntactically incorrect.

To achieve what you need you should remove the integers in the argument list, fix the mis-matched bracket at the end of the DOMReady handler and you can also remove the `- 1 + 1` from the `Math.random` value.

Try this:

```
var x = function getRandomInt() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
}
$('#x').html(x);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/113/)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply, Rory!

Comment: Sorry - I'm a novice, and already have a follow up question. I tried to expand it with another variable that's, in turn, less than X.  Is there a super obvious mistake in my code? http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/118/

Comment: The `x` variable is a function, so you need to invoke it with `x()`: http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/119/

Comment: Thanks again, Rory. That helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$('#x').html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 ) + 1);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KDmwn/114/)

Comment: Awesomely simple. Thanks!